# minimal fractions with matching decimal expansions to 18 places

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers

I am wondering if there is a good method for finding two positive rational numbers that differ in their decimal expansion after 18 decimal places (i.e. the first 17 decimals should be the same). I want the fractions to have minimal denominators, where "minimal" here can be defined as minimizing the sum of the denominators.

I initially tried starting with something like 1/19 or 1/29 and trying to find a second one from there, but all my attempts produced far too large number for the second fraction. I though I would check with there was someone who had already thought through this and had a nice method already.

Comment: Hint : Note that the difference is at least $\frac{1}{m}$ , where $m$ is the product of the numerators.

Comment: ...denominators

Comment: That implies I will never do better than two 10 digit numbers, which was what I kind of feared ...

Comment: I believe that continued fractions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) can be of help

Comment: @Empy2 Yes, of course ...